# We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content M2

Tags: magento2, category

I have checked log file **exc.log**

> [2020-01-06 11:20:35] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/exmp.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/subcategory.phtml
>   on line 5 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: Notice: Undefined
>   offset: 2 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/exmp.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog//category/subcategory.phtml
>   on line 5 at
>   /var/www/vhosts/exmp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/
>   ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

**subcategory.phtml** File Code

```
<?php

$curr_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$exp_url = explode('/', $curr_url);
//print_r($exp_url);
if($exp_url[2] == 'xyz.html' || $exp_url[2] == 'xyz'){
    $classType='xyz';
    }else if($exp_url[2] == 'abc.html' || $exp_url[2] == 'abc'){ 
        $classType='abc xyz;
        }else{
            $classType='tool-another';
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your code with below code.

```
<?php

$curr_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$exp_url = explode('/', $curr_url);
//print_r($exp_url);

$classType = 'tool-another';
if(!empty($exp_url) && isset($exp_url[2]) )
{
    if($exp_url[2] == 'xyz.html' || $exp_url[2] == 'xyz'){
        $classType = 'xyz';
    } elseif($exp_url[2] == 'abc.html' || $exp_url[2] == 'abc'){ 
       $classType = 'abc xyz';
    }
}

?>
```

Let me know if you are still getting this issue.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Its working thankyou

Comment: Please accept this answer if it work for you.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted.